# Buck converter confusing output voltage waveform

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, buck, matlab, simulink

I've constructed a simple DC-DC buck converter circuit in Simulink with ideal components.

I'm getting a weird output voltage waveform. Although the average output voltage matches my calculations, the waveform does not look uniform.

Any idea as to why there's high peaks from 0.02s to 0.03s and very low peaks from 0.03s to 0.04s? This pattern continues on when I extend the simulation time.

[image: Simulink schematic]

[image: Output voltage waveform]

replica of the above in LTspice,

[image: LTspice]

Comment: You are reducing the chances of getting a decent answer by not posting a proper schematic. It looks like it's going into burst mode but I'm unsure because of the obscurity of your choice of schematic.

Comment: @ash:  If I'm reading the diagram correctly, all you have is a fixed duty cycle driving the switch.  There doesn't seem to be any feedback or a controller of any kind involved.  You are looking at a theoretical buck converter, not a practical one.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Andyaka To clarify further, i implemented an exact replica of this circuit in ltspice. That produced the expected output waveform unlike this simulink one.
May i know what you exactly mean by proper schematic? i will be happy to provide all necessary info

Comment: @JRE, yep a theoretical one

Comment: @Ash also show the LTSpice circuit for comparison. This is fundamentally a site about electronics and it massively helps if you show circuit diagrams and not block diagrams (even if they do have functionality in simulink).

Comment: The two simulations are not the same. The voltage source in LTSpice applies a voltage then applies zero volts. Simulink applies a voltage then an open.

Comment: You should select a diode in LTspice. A Schottky perhaps

Comment: @RussellH, updated the circuit. this should be alright yeah? and why cant i use an ideal diode? This circuit is just for theoretical purposes. Not to implement irl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution to this problem. The issue was in the Simulink's configuration parameter window->solver tab. I reduced the max step size from 2.5e-5 to 1e-6. Now the waveform looks as expected,

[image]

[image]